# rotation problems when a UIAlertView is showing in iOS 7

Tags: ios7, uialertview

in iOS7, rarely but occassionally, when I rotate my app while a `UIAlertView` is showing, only the alertView and the status bar rotate, and not my app. Has anybody else experienced this and/or have found a workaround?

Comment: None of the below worked for me, though I haven't re-tested in 7.1 yet

Answer (score 15):

I've resolved this issue by adding the next method to app delegate:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application willChangeStatusBarOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)newStatusBarOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration  {
NSArray *windows = [application windows];
for (UIWindow *nextWindow in windows) {
    [[nextWindow.rootViewController class] attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation];
     }
}
```

Comment: That fixed my problem and it seems absolutely reasonable! But I wonder if it's an iOS 7+ bug since they have changed the UIALertView's hierarchy in iOS 7.

Comment: @user3404693 Because you can't use UIAlertView in iOS8. Use UIAlertController instead. There's no guarantee (according to my experience) that UIAlertView would work correctly with iOS8.

Answer (score 4):

I had the opposite problem. My app would rotate but the alert view would not rotate. I found out that this was because I was showing the alert view immediately after a `UIActionSheet` was dismissed (so while it's dismissal animation was taking place). This seemed to be triggering a bug that will make the alert view not rotate with the app (and some other minor visual problems later). I solved this by presenting the alert view a half second after the action sheet begins to dismiss, like this:

```
[alertView performSelector:@selector(show) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
```

Comment: i wasn't showing a `UIActionSheet`, but rather dismissing a view controller just as the `UIAlertView` was being displayed, and this solved the problem.

Comment: This is how it happens in my app!

Comment: Fixed my bug. Thanks. This is only needed on iOS 7 not iOS 8 or iOS 6 for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think the root of the problem in iOS7 that Apple changed the *UIAlertView* appearance mechanism.
From now any show of alertView follows after initiating of two private view controllers

```
_UIModalItemAppViewController
_UIModalItemsPresentingViewController
```

In other words, now UIAlertView is not a pure view - it is a part of some complicated collection of view controllers with full view controller life cycle.