# UIViewController doesn't rotate if UIAlertView is shown

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, rotation, uialertview

My UIViewController doesn't rotate if UIAlertView is shown. And I can't get what I'm doing wrong or if this is a default behavior of iOS.

UIAlertView and status bar rotates without issues. If I cancel UIAlertView everything starts rotating cool again.

Comment: Did you try the answers from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19850434/rotation-problems-when-a-uialertview-is-showing-in-ios-7

Comment: Sure, I doesn't work for me. I'm thinking if this is a common issue or not. I was able to get this behavior after creating blank app and showing alertview on viewDidLoad.