# Status bar rotates twice when changing interface orientation

Tags: ios, interface, orientation, status

I have an iPad app which supports only Landscape (left and right) orientations. When rotating the device the status bar should rotate together with the interface (180°), but it actually rotates twice (180° + 360°).

Happens only in iOS 8, on lower versions there's no such problem. I was able to reproduce this in Photos app as well. Anyone knows how to work around this?

Comment: Is it happening only in a particular view controller or entire application?

Comment: @thavasidurai It is happening everywhere in the app, and status bar appearance is view-controller based.

Comment: Do you have multiple views attached to a UIWindow? pre iOS8 only the rootViewController & first UIView gets rotated. on IOS8 it seams all views attached to UIWindow get rotated.

Comment: @over_optimistic The UIWindow has only one subview, if that's what you mean by 'attached view', and I set the rootViewController (not the view) to the UIWindow before I call makeKeyAndVisible on it. No other view controller is presented, but more views are added to my unique view controller's view (the view controller set on the window) which acts as a container of other controllers. I don't think that matters, the point is I have only one view controller that is always presented and controls the status bar appearance, and the UIWindow has its view attached.

Comment: Hi @AndreiMarincas, I'm having the same problem as you had. Did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: @ThomasKeuleers Not yet, we are expecting this to be fixed in a future iOS update.

Comment: @AndreiMarincas, I did find something. I was calling "attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation" somewhere in my code to fix this bug: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19850434/rotation-problems-when-a-uialertview-is-showing-in-ios-7 . The rotation works just fine if I remove this

Comment: @ThomasKeuleers Thanks, I will try that out, right now I'm busy with another project